# Brew installation of npm is now giving error/issue

Tags: laravel, npm, homebrew

I did a brew install node.  Now I'm getting the following whenever I try to use commands like php artisan, valet, etc.:

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.61.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found

I'm running macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.5.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Node.  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling icu4c.  I have tried unlinking and relinking.  Anyone else encountered this and have a solution?

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor` ?

Comment: "Your system is ready to brew."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed everything npm and node related (I think), did a brew upgrade php, and now everything seems to be working.  I'll continue to troubleshoot and see if I can find out more.

Comment: I didn't even remove npm. Just a `brew upgrade php` did the job.

Comment: what's reason lead to this question?

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this question.

On the way:

First:
1  brew upgrade php

2 look PHP in your $PAHT ?
if not in PATH

> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@5.6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
>
> echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@5.6/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

It works for me!